# Full page popup ad via HTML

Tags: html

I want to do a popup/takover ad on my WordPress website. The ad should take over the whole visible area, so if a user tries to scroll down, the ad should scroll with him, so maybe this could be done via the CSS of the element? The ad shouldn't even have an option for closing because our client gave as a bloody .swf file to put as an ad, and the flash itself has closing options, redirects etc.

So just a solution for putting an popup ad via HTML and positioning it via CSS should be fine. The ad should pop up in the same window of course, not a new tab or new window.

If you need any more info please let me know, I don't even know how would I write the code. I tried fiddling with the WordPress plugins but I'm not really satisfied.

Comment: `position:fixed; z-index:999999; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;` done! That'll be $20 please.

Comment: We're here to help you when you write your own code, not do your programming for you. Especially not if YOU are being paid for it.

Comment: Well I'm not actually paid by this because I'm doing it pro bono, but sure...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the ad in an absolutely positioned DIV.

HTML:

```
<div class="full-ad">
  <!-- ... Ad goes here ... -->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.full-ad {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  /* depending on your other code, you may need to set an appropriate a-index as well */
{
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="ads">
<!-- YOUR ADS CODE -->
</span>
<style>
.ads{
min-width: 100%;
min-height: 100%;
margin: 0;
position:fixed;
}
</style>
```